# How do I merge a JSON child with it's parent using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON like so:

```json
{
  "parent": {
    "type": "Object",
    "value": {
        "childName": { "type": "String", "value": "A string" }
       }
   }
}
```

Pretty much, the pattern is `parent` has `type` and `value`, but I want the value of `parent` to be `value`

```json
{
  "parent": {
    "childName": "A string"
  }
}
```

How can I set the parent's value to be the child named `value` recursively in JavaScript?

The main issue I am having is doing this recursively for a very large file.

Examples:

The start value of `Level` is `{ "type": "string", "value": "A string" }

I want to make the value of `Level` become "A String", making the end value of `Level` become "A String"

---

The start value of `parentObject` is `{ "type": "Object", "value": { "anotherObject": { "type": "string", "value": "Another string" }, "secondObject": { "type": "string", "value": "second string" } } }`

I want to make the value of `parentObject` become `{ "anotherObject": { "type": "string", "value": "Another string" }, "secondObject": { "type": "string", "value": "second string" } }`

And the value of `anotherObject` become "Another string"

Making the final result

```json
{"parentObject": { "anotherObject": "Another string" }, { "secondObject": "second string" }}
```

---

[Here is a example JSON file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gbsXuk1gwyFgj8ygRlu291QGSwp2j_Hj/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Could you be more clear?  From what I see, all you need is `obj['parent']` = `obj['parent']['value']`?

Comment: May you add some more output so we can see different examples? Also please add your effort so far as a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing is the object should be symmetric if your want to do it in a recursive way.

Example:

```
const input = {
  "parentObject": {
    "type": "Object",
    "value": {
      "anotherObject": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "Another string"
      }
    }
  }
};
```

The recursive function is something like this.

```js
const input = {
  "parentObject": {
    "type": "Object",
    "value": {
      "anotherObject1": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "Another string"
      },
      "anotherObject2": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "Another string"
      }
    }
  }
};

const recursivefn = (obj) => {
    const keys = Object.keys(obj);
    let acc = {}
    keys.forEach((key)=>{
      if (typeof obj[key].value === 'object') {
          acc = { ...acc, [key]: recursivefn(obj[key].value) };
      } else {
          acc = { ...acc, [key]: obj[key].value};
      }
    });
    return acc;
}
console.log(recursivefn(input));
```

Comment: Yes and no, you got the write concept, except the name will not always be `parent` - I edited my post with an example

Comment: I updated the code try it. If this is what you expected approve the code ;)

Comment: I works like a charm, but... I forgot to mention that sometimes there are multiple children, like `{ "parentName": { "type": "Object", "value": { childOne: { type: "String", value: "A String" }, childTwo: { "type": "Object", "value": { ... } } } } }`

Comment: so what is that you expect in the output. if all the other children have same kind of object then it should be simple

Comment: Pretty much: Your code works! But, can you adjust to work for multiple child objects instead one. Here is one of the files: [file URL](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gbsXuk1gwyFgj8ygRlu291QGSwp2j_Hj/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231657/discussion-between-awesomemaker3000-and-punith-mithra).